# Pandas pct_change() with zero as divisor

Tags: pandas

I have a following dataframe,

```
df_num = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 3], 'col2': [0, 3]})
df_num

    col1    col2
0   1       0
1   3       3
```

I want to get the percentage change between the two rows, for that I am using the `pct_change()` option. And this is the result,

```
df_num.pct_change().iloc[-1]

col1    2.0
col2    inf
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```

It is noticed that the col2 `pct_change` value is `inf`. Mathematically this is correct!

But I want some thing like this,

```
df_num_div = df_num.loc[0].replace(0, 1)
(df_num.loc[1] - df_num.loc[0]) / df_num_div

col1    2.0
col2    3.0
dtype: float64
```

Is it possible to do this in an efficient way (may be with some implicit function in pandas), without replacing `0` with `1` just for divisor?

Answer (score 0):

One hacky way to do it is to instead just do the `pct_change()` operation, then replace the infinities with the original value at that location from `df_num`, since we know we would've replaced the divisor with `1` anyways.

```py
pct_ch_df = df_num.pct_change()
df_num[np.isinf(pct_ch_df)].combine_first(pct_ch_df).iloc[-1]

col1    2.0
col2    3.0
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```